# What does | and << mean?

Tags: objective-c

Sorry if this is a common question but I don't know what it's called so I'm having trouble searching for it.

How does this work:

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

I understand that it means that the view gets both flexible width and height, but how does it store two variables like that?

If i look at the typedef for UIViewAutoresizing it looks like:

```
enum {
    UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
...
```

So, how can one variable store more than one value like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"|" is a bitwise 'or'.

"<<" is also a bitwise operation shifting. it moves all the bits to the left:

```
00100 << 1 = 01000
```

Read the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation), you're interested in "or" and shift operations.

Answer (score 3):

These are C bit level operators.

`|` is binary or: 0001 | 0010 = 0011.

`<<` is a bit shift: 0001 << 1 = 0010.

They are used for [bitmasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29).